# button.bind not calling function tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Button clicks are calling the corresponding function that prints to console.  (printing is just a placeholder for now) - I'm just experimenting with the functionality at this point.  Thanks in advance

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def load_json_button(event):
    print("Load JSON")

def save_json_button():
    print("Save JSON")

def select_property_button():
    print("Select Property")

def save_property_button():
    print("Save Property")

top_frame = Frame(root, width=450, height=300)
top_frame.pack()

button1 = Button(top_frame, text="Load JSON",fg="blue")
button1.bind("<Button-1>", load_json_button)
button1.pack(side=LEFT)

button2 = Button(top_frame, text="Save JSON", fg="green")
button2.bind("<Button-1>", save_json_button)
button2.pack(side=RIGHT)

button3 = Button(top_frame, text="Select Property", fg="purple")
button3.bind("<Button-1>", select_property_button)
button3.pack(side=RIGHT)

button4 = Button(top_frame, text="Save Property", fg="black")
button4.bind("<Button-1>", save_property_button)
button4.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I run your code, the functions are being called. Some of them throw errors because you've defined them wrong, but they are being called. If you're just learning, you should be using the `command` attribute of a button rather than `bind`.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley - How did I define them wrong?

Comment: When you use `bind`, the called function is passed an object which represents the event. Some of your functions don't accept an argument.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks Bryan, I see now :)